# Google Eclipse Plugin - Work with Python

Tags: python, eclipse, google-app-engine

Does the Google Eclipse Plugin work at all with Pydev or is it only useful if I am developing in Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The App Engine eclipse plugin is for Java development. As Casebash points out, though Pydev now has [App Engine integration](http://pydev.blogspot.com/2009/05/testing-on-pydev-146-google-app-engine.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can, indeed, use Eclipse (and PyDev) for Python development for App Engine -- see [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/eclipse.html) for more, for example!

Comment: So there is no need to install the Google Eclipse Plugin - just work with Pydev?

Comment: Actually, Pydev now supports this. http://pydev.blogspot.com/2009/05/testing-on-pydev-146-google-app-engine.html